# When I try to fetch data to a url with {% url %} for implementing PayPal checkout, urls are not found. Why?

Tags: python, django, url, fetch, jinja2

I am implementing PayPal checkout for my website using Django, and having some trouble with url. Once the payment is complete I want to fetch data to 'payment_complete' view and then send the customer to 'payment_successful' page.

But it does not work. The urls 'payment_complete' and 'payment_successful' are not found. Do you know why ? Thank you for your help.

#### checkout.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}

Checkout

{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    <div> 
        
        <div id = "proceed-to-payment-div">
            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Ac7c5n8LPoPfEjQjK-PlndbIoLLYm5t5z7Pw8YSPVhMtpU5PJDLmjDxDXO5sYZGl4sBNX-AdgjbGxOuv&currency=EUR" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var basket_total = '{{basket.get_total_price}}';
        console.log(basket_total);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src=" {%  static 'js/payment/checkout-paypal.js' %} "></script>

{% endblock content %}
```

#### checkout-paypal.js

```
function initPayPalButton() {

    paypal.Buttons({
        style:{
            color:'white',
            shape:'rect',
            size:'responsive'
        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: parseFloat(basket_total).toFixed(2)
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        onApprove: function(data) {
            var url = "{% url 'payment:payment_complete' %}"

            return fetch(url, {
                method:'POST',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    orderID: data.orderID
                })
            }).then(function () {
                location.href = "{% url 'payment:payment_successful' %}";
            });
        },
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
};

initPayPalButton();
```

#### urls.py (core of the website)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls', namespace='store')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
    path('basket/', include('basket.urls', namespace='basket')),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('payment/', include('payment.urls', namespace='payment')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

#### urls.py (payment app)

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'payment'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('payment_complete/', views.payment_complete, name='payment_complete'),
    path('payment_successful/', views.payment_successful, name='payment_successful'),
]
```

#### views.py (payment app)

```
import json

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.views import View 
from django.conf import settings 
from django.http import JsonResponse 

from paypalcheckoutsdk.orders import OrdersGetRequest
from .paypal import PayPalClient

from basket.basket import Basket 
from orders.models import OrderItem, Order


def checkout(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'payment/checkout.html', context)



def payment_complete(request):

    PPClient = PayPalClient()

    body = json.loads(request.body)
    data = body["orderID"]
    user_id = request.user.id

    requestorder = OrdersGetRequest(data)

    response = PPClient.client.execute(requestorder)

    total_paid = response.result.purchase_units[0].amount.value

    basket = Basket(request)

    for item in basket:
        OrderItem.objects.create(
            product=item["product"],
            price=item["price"],
            quantity=item["qty"],
            subtotal = float(item["price"]) * int(item["qty"]),
            )

    order = Order.objects.create(
        user_id = user_id,
        name = response.result.purchase_units[0].shipping.name.full_name,
        email = response.result.payer.email_address,
        address1 = response.result.purchase_units[0].shipping.address.address_line_1,
        address2 = response.result.purchase_units[0].shipping.address.address_line_2,
        postcode = response.result.purchase_units[0].shipping.address.postal_code,
        country = response.result.purchase_units[0].shipping.address.country_code,
        city = response.result.purchase_units[0].shipping.address.city,
        total_paid = total_paid,
        order_key = response.result.id,
        payment_option = "paypal",
        billing_status = True,
        )

    order_id = order.pk

    return JsonResponse("Payment completed OK", safe=False)


def payment_successful(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    basket.clear()

    return render(request, "payment/payment_successful.html",{})
```

#### error messsage in the shell

```
[04/Apr/2021 00:00:11] "POST /basket/update/ HTTP/1.1" 200 46
[04/Apr/2021 00:00:13] "GET /payment/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6391
[04/Apr/2021 00:00:13] "GET /static/js/payment/checkout-paypal.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /payment/{% url 'payment:payment_complete' %}
[04/Apr/2021 00:00:34] "POST /payment/%7B%%20url%20'payment:payment_complete'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 3846
Not Found: /payment/{% url 'payment:payment_successful' %}
[04/Apr/2021 00:00:34] "GET /payment/%7B%%20url%20'payment:payment_successful'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 3851
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[04/Apr/2021 00:00:34] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3240
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use {% url %} template tags in your checkout-paypal.js, it is a static file, not parsed by the templating engine. You'll have to hard-code your urls in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Re-define your url as follows, on the paypal OnApprove part.

```
var url='/payment/payment_complete/'
```

The JavaScript file checkout-paypal.js is not parsed by the templating engine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).